# Validate list of columns for a similar condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

I am trying to validate this list of columns for the presence. So I wrote this code. It's works but can we create an array of columns for this?
Example that I wrote:

```
class UserAccount < ApplicationRecord

  self.table_name = 'accounts'

  belongs_to :user

  with_options unless: :new_record? do
    validates :address, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
    validates :street, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
    validates :house_number, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
    validates :zip_code, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
    validates :city, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
    validates :country, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
  end

end
```

Array of columns to iterate on:

```
REQUIRED_COLUMNS = %w[address street house_number zip_code city country]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[validates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.3/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) can take multiple columns as the first args, so you could just provide all columns on one line, i.e.

```
validates :address, :street, :etc, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
```

If you do want to use an array for this, you should be able to use the [splat](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) operator, i.e.

```
REQUIRED_COLUMNS = %i(address street house_number zip_code city country).freeze
validates *REQUIRED_COLUMNS, presence: { message: 'This field is required' }
```

Notice I've switched to `%i()` to generate an array of symbols.

Using the `splat` operator, in a very small nutshell, destructures the array so its contents are passed as individual args, rather than just one array argument.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
validates_presence_of :address, :street, :house_number, :zip_code, :city, :country, unless: :new_record?
```

Notice that I removed your `message` declaration. This way the validation will use the default message which includes the name of the field that has failed validation – i.e. `"City can't be blank."` – instead of just saying `"This field is required."` with no explanation to the user as to what `"This"` is.